# How do I create this Table/View in Asp.Net C#

Tags: asp.net

[image][I need to create a Table as per the following Image and I'm a newbie to .Net. Please tell me which tool I should be using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc5if.jpg)

Comment: out of context, curious about which tool you used to generate this stub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this looks like an accordion where each section holds a table with data for a specific date. What you could do in this case is to dynamically create DIV objects (for each data that you intend to represent) and in each div add GridView or DataGrid. Then you would have style those divs to get the desired look. On the other hand have a look at jQuery UI Accordion. I understand you are a novice but jQuery UI Accordion could help solve your problem http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/.

Comment: That was very helpful. Now I got a fair bit of idea on how to use jQuery UI to create ACCORDION. But I was how to do this dynamically. If you see the above example, I'm getting all the data from the database, so how do I set that up dynamically. Your help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a trivial structure to implement.

You would probably want to start with a `ListView` or a `Repeater`. A Repeater is simpler to use, but has more limitations.

Then, inside each `Item Template` of your `Repeater` or `ListView`, you're going to need a `GridView`. The `GridView` will handle the data table and the paging.

You can either handle the `Selected` event of the `ListView` to determine which row to expand, and only populate that row on the server side, or you can populate all rows and use a client-side script to show/hide the rows. It's up to you which approach will work best given your data.

You'll need to do a two-level databinding, where first you bind the `ListView` to your main set of data, in this case it looks like a list of dates. Then, in the `ItemDataBound` event of the `ListView`, bind each list view item's internal `GridView`. You may want to do this only for the row that should be shown.

There are ways this could be optimized, for sure, with a custom control for each row, and so on, but this is the basic idea.